# Prove that G is Hamiltonian

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonicity

Given $G$ a graph with degrees:$6,6,4,4,4,k,k$ on $7$ vertices and $10$ regions 
(and by Euler $n-f+r=2$ I found that $k$=3)
prove $G$ is contains a Hamiltonian cycle

I did find a visual cycle on the actual graph, where in the solutions (by a student) he proved that vertex 3 doesn't have to be a neighbor with the other vertex degree 3 and thus by the theorem the graph is hamiltonian

What will be a better explanation in a discrete math course

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is... a Hamiltonian cycle in your graph:

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you , so my intuition about finding it by the actual graph is correct rather than trying to prove it by theorems

Answer (score 0):

If  the sum of every pair of vertices is at least n than your graph has a Hamiltonian cycle.
Also if you can prove that this graph has a cyclic graph C7 as a subgraph than it is also Hamiltonian.

Comment: dont think i properly understood it about the $C_7$ Just to show there is a Cycle length 7 as a subgraph than it is proving the Hamiltonian graph ?

Comment: If you can find a cyclic graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory) with  7 vertices as a subgraph in your original graph than this qualifies it to have a hamiltonian cycle because you can simply traverse the cycle and you would have your hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: ok, i think i do understand